# How to find the total number of checkboxes present on web page using Selenium Webdriver - Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

**Environment: Selenium Webdriver Using Java**

1) run a Search 
2) after search 5 items will be displayed with 5 check-boxes against them
3) I want to get the number of check-boxes
4) check-boxes have class name "checkbox"

Please suggest

Thanks !!

Comment: plz paste some html code of page you want to test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickest and simplest method is to find a list of the checkbox elements by the className you've provided.

```
List<WebElement> boxes = driver.findElements(By.className("checkbox"));
int numberOfBoxes = boxes.length();
```

If you want the number of checkboxes per search result, you'd need to loop for each result.

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//relevant_xpath_from_your_html"));
for (Webelement result : results){
     List<WebElement> boxes = result.findElements(By.className("checkbox"));
     int numberOfBoxes = boxes.length()
}
```

Comment: @MandeepRehal [If this answer proved to be useful and correct, consider accepting it. That way, future readers will know this question is resolved and that this answer is the correct and working one.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184794)

Answer (score 0):

The following will show all checkboxes present on a page

```
System.out.println(
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).size()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class Checkbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\java\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='checkBoxOption1']")).click();//select checkbox 1
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='checkBoxOption1']")).isSelected());//validated checkbox selection
        
        //Thread.sleep(4000);//delay process to see the check and uncheck activity

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='checkBoxOption1']")).click();//deselect checkbox 1
        Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='checkBoxOption1']")).isSelected());//validated checkbox deselection
        
        //to get checkbox counts on the page.
        System.out.println("The checkbox count is "+ driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).size());//select checkbox 1

    }

}
```